# Преобразование списка в строку Python

Tags: python, list

Есть код который берет из Эксель столбик, преобразует каждую строку в массив, миксует в нем слова.
На выходе должны получиться строки, а выводятся массивы

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def gencombs(comb, lst, idx):
    if idx >= len(lst):
        print(comb)
    else:
        for i in range(len(comb),-1, -1):
            gencombs(comb[:i] + [lst[idx]] + comb[i:], lst, idx + 1)
        gencombs(comb, lst, idx + 1)
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Iclub\Desktop\parserTest.xls', sheet_name='Sheet1')
var1 = df['first (A1)'].tolist()

for i in range(len(var1)):
    array = np.array(var1[i])

for i in var1:
    last = i.split()
    momo = gencombs([], last, 0)
empty_lists = [-1] + [i for i, x in enumerate(momo) if x == []]
parsed_momo = [[' '.join(x) for x in momo[(empty_lists[i - 1] + 1):(empty_lists[i] - 1)]] for i in range(1, len(empty_lists))]
for x in parsed_momo:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
['first', '1']
['1', 'first']
['first']
['1']
[]
['third', '2']
['2', 'third']
['third']
['2']
[]
['white', '3']
['3', 'white']
['white']
['3']
[]
```

Нужный output:

```
first 1, 1 first, 1, first
third 2, 2 third, 2, third
white 3, 3 white, 3, white
```

Comment: DataFrame или пример скрина Excel файла можете приложить?

Comment: Итерироваться по строкам для пандас массива - это плохая идея. Сделай лучше функцию, которую вызовешь через apply